# Is there another way to output Categories and all respective entries other than category_archive?

Tags: categories, entries, navigation, category-archive

I'm trying to output a category group and its respective entry listing titles (in this case the titles are names of people) in alphabetical order by last name in a menu navigation like so. To do this, I've created a custom field called `last_name` thinking I could use this tag `orderby="last_name`, but because `category_archive` doesn't support this parameter, I'm not able to accomplish this way.

- Category 1

  - Jon Doe
  - Jane Doe
  - Janet Doe
- Category 2

  - Jon Doe
  - Jane Doe

Here's the code I have:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled main-list">
    {exp:channel:category_archive channel="speakers" style="linear" backspace="7" show="not 28}
        <li>
            {categories}
                <a class="btn-open" href="#">{category_name}</a>
            {/categories} 
            <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
                {entry_titles}  
                    <li><a href="{path='site/speaker'}">{title}</a></li>
                {/entry_titles}     
            </ul> 
        </li>   
    {/exp:channel:category_archive}     
</ul>
```

Is there any other way to accomplish so I can get a bit more flexibility. Perhaps playa or some other plugin or native code? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, something like this:

```
{exp:channel:category_archive channel="my_channel" style="linear"}
    {categories}
            <h3>{category_name}</h3>

        {exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" category="{category_id}"}
            <a href="{comment_url_title_path}">{title}</a>
        {/exp:channel:entries}

    {/categories}
{/exp:channel:category_archive}
```

Comment: added my custom field to use for sorting and worked great, `orderby="last_name" search:navigation_exclude="not y" sort="asc"`. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I just realized my the urls of my entries are outputting `example.com/site/speaker/C1`, using the template path `{path='site/speaker'}`. Any idea how to resolve issue?

Comment: Disregard, duh! Used this and working fine, `{url_title_path='site/speaker'}`